# ¿Como puedo hacer un petición ajax y dependiendo del resultado llamar otro ajax para actualizar datos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Hola intento hacer una petición ajax para actualizar unos datos, después que haga la actualización quiero llamar a la función que crea los elementos en mi página para actualizar lo que se ve, pero esta función también utiliza un ajax para ir por los datos. Pero este proceso no lo hace, ya intente usando ajax sincrono y usando when/then pero no logro que después de modificar los datos se actualizen los datos mostrados.
Aquí el código:

```
$('#modificar').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    credito = {}
    credito['id'] = idCred
    credito['nombre'] = $('#editName').val()
    credito['value'] = $('#editValue').val()
    credito['desc'] = $('#editDesc').val()
    opt = ""
    if (typeCred == '1') {
        opt = "updateCred1"
    } else if (typeCred == '2'){
        opt = "updateCred2"
    } else {
        opt = "updateCred3"
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "access/creditos.php",
        async: false,
        data:{
            'opt': opt,
            'credit' : credito,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                M.toast({html : 'Se ha modificado correctamente'})
                loadCred()
            } else {
                M.toast({html : 'Error Interno del Servidor'})
            }
        }
    })
})
```

loadCred() es la otra función que actualiza lo mostrado en pantalla usando otro ajax. Gracias por contestar c:

Comment: Bueno por si alguien tiene este problema y está creando objetos html desde el js, lo que tiene que hacer es vaciar el div o el contenedor antes de volver de llenarlo

Comment: ¿Has debugado el proceso? Comprobando que realmente entre en la segunta función de ajax y en ese caso que devuelva un success? Son muchos factores que podrían dar el fallo lo mejor intentar acotarlo.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, si debuggie y si me regresaba succes y también entraba en la otra función. Lo que lo resolvió es que borrara el contenido del div donde se cargaban los datos antes de actualizrlos